# PHP and Vue integration

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, routes, directory-structure

Recently I've been involved in a Project, a PHP panel. It uses pure PHP and they have given me permission to access a folder to add my functionalities as an add-on to the existing panel.

The file structure is like so:

```
/
├── assets/                      
│   └── ...
├── config/
│   └── ...
├── test/
│   └── ...
.
.
.
├── MYAPP/
│   └── api/  
│   │   ├── foo/  
│   ├── index.html 
│   └── ...
.
.
.
├── myApp.php
├── ...
```

myApp.php file has some requires to PHP files to load the theme and some scripts at the top and at the bottom.
I can require the index.html from MYAPP folder to load the main page of the app itself with all of the scripts and stylesheets working correctly as it is located in the root.

The URL now is “webpage.com/myApp.php”

Is it possible to create an SPA using the current file myApp.php with Vue and Vue-router like so?

- “webpage.com/myApp.php/#/addCategory”
- “webpage.com/myApp.php/#/editCategory”
- …

Or should I make URL calls like this and load the content old fashion way?

- “webpage.com/myApp.php? page=addCategory”
- “webpage.com/myApp.php? page=editCategory”
  -...

I have tried the vue spa template changing the base option with the vue-router but it didn't work.
What could be my options? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just install and import properly the vue-router to your project. Here's Vue and Vue Router documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: thanks both it worked fine